# Laravel Eloquent: get all records sorted by summary price from relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have these models:

```
Vendor (id, title)
Service (id, vendor_id, type, price)
```

Relationship: `Vendor hasMany Service`

I need to select all vendors, sorted by the summary price of the services they provide (with the certain service type)

For example, here's the sample data for services table:

```
1  |  1  |  development  |  10
2  |  2  |  development  |  20
3  |  1  |  testing      |  20
4  |  1  |  testing      |  15
5  |  1  |  other        |  15
```

With Eloquent, how to select all vendors (who provide "development" and "testing" services), sorted by summary of all services price?

Answer (score 1):

```
$vendor = Vendor::with(['services' => function($query) {
    $query->whereIn('name', ['development', 'testing'])
        ->orderBy('price');
}])->get();
```

Comment: I know all this. But how to get "summary_price"? There's no such column and I need to do my math behind the scenes to calculate the summary. Is it possible with Eloquent or only raw SQL is the solution?

Comment: 'summary price' is the sum of the prices in Service?

Comment: Yes, how to get it? See the question. I do not need to sort by price, I need to sort by summary price of all services for each vendor.

Comment: I think the best way to do that would be with a custom collection, you might want to check this out: http://heera.it/extend-laravel-eloquent-collection-object